# Sweet alert is overriding the previous alert in a loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, sweetalert

i am call the sweet alert function on inside a loop but sweetalert is only showing me one time,i think it is overriding the previous sweetalert,bcz when i do the simple alert it does pop up twice then but sweet alert is only showing me one time.
What i want to do is to to sweet alert to show the second or third alert when i click on ok aor cancel button otherwise dont't shwo the second or next alert according to loop itreration
Here is my code

```
$.each(data,function(index,elem){

     NotificationPopUpIsApprove();

});

function NotificationPopUpIsApprove(){
     swal({
          title: "Are you sure?",
          text: "The Task "+ task_name + " In Project " + project_name + "is Completed by " + uname ,
          type: "warning",
          confirmButtonText: "Approve!",
          closeOnConfirm: false,
          confirmButtonColor: "#44E753",
          cancelButtonText: "Reasssign!",
          showCancelButton: true,

    },
    function(isConfirm){
      if (isConfirm === true) {
        return true;
      }else{
        return false;
      }
    });

}
```

Thanks in advance..

Comment: what is defined in "data"

Comment: an array which i am getting from database using jquery ajax request

Answer (score 2):

**$.each** is a synchronous jQuery method, so it wont wait for sweetalert's response which triggers this behaviour.

Given your requirment, hope this helps.

```
    var data = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
    var task_name = "sweetalert";
    var project_name = "Something";
    var uname ="SweetAlert"

    $(document).ready(function () {
        NotificationCheck(data[0]);
    });

    function NotificationCheck(noti) {
        is_last = (data.indexOf(noti) + 1 == data.length);

        NotificationPopUpIsApprove(is_last, function (boool) {
            if (boool) { // Do something with response from user
                console.log(noti);
            }

            if (data.indexOf(noti) < (data.length)) { // Inject next element for user response
                next = data.indexOf(noti) + 1;
                NotificationCheck(data[next]);
            }

        });
    }

    function NotificationPopUpIsApprove(is_last, callback) {
        swal({
            title: "Are you sure?",
            text: "The Task " + task_name + " In Project " + project_name + "is Completed by " + uname,
            type: "warning",
            confirmButtonText: "Approve!",
            closeOnConfirm: false,
            confirmButtonColor: "#44E753",
            cancelButtonText: "Reasssign!",
            showCancelButton: true,
        },

        function (isConfirm) {
            if (is_last) { //Close SweetAlert box
                swal.close();
            }
            callback(isConfirm); //Sends user's response
        });

    }
```