How do I use sweetalert on each item in an array?
I'm trying to use JQuery to loop over an array of strings, and for each item use sweetalert1.0 to prompt the user with a confirm and cancel button. I'm only getting one sweetalert prompt for the last item in the array. Below is the code I've tried. It only shows swal() for letter "C" and not "A" or "B".  Can someone please help?
let array_letters = ["A", "B", "C"];

$.each(array_letters, function (i, letter) {
    swal({
         title: "Print " + swal_title + "?",
         type: "warning",
         closeOnConfirm: true,
         showConfirmButton: true,
         confirmButtonText: "Yes",
         showCancelButton: true,
     });
});


Where are you getting swal_title from? Your code doesn't match your description atm.

Only built-in alerts block JS threads, so you are calling sweet alert for each array element one after another with your loop (effectively, all at the same time). I don't know for sure, but presumably sweet alert overwrites the previous alert when a new one is called.

Do you want the user to answer each alert before the next one opens, or show all 3 at once?   Potential solution, depends on your requirement: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30366694/sweet-alert-is-overriding-the-previous-alert-in-a-loop  edit: probably a better solution using swal's queue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56404231/sweet-alert-is-overriding-the-one-alert-in-a-loop/56405081#56405081 and one using async https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38085851/sweetalert2-multiple-swal-at-the-same-function

And an existing question if your requirement is show all at once: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42269423/multiple-modals-with-sweet-alert-2 (you can't, swal doesn't allow that)

swal_title should be letter.  Sorry about that.

I would like one alert at a time. I would like the first alert to prompt with a yes and no button. If they select yes, I would like to make an ajax call, once ajax is complete show second alert, and so on through the array. If they click no just exit and return to main page. I'll take a look at the links you sent and keep you posted. Thank you!!

Thank you fdomn-m!!  Your first link worked. I appreciate the quick response and help!
